# ext4 disk modified by windows 10 and now lost all files on that drive

Tags: windows-10, ssd, data-recovery, ext4

I had a 250GB SATA SSD and 500GB SATA SSD. I first used Ubuntu OS installed on the 250GB SSD and used the 500GB SSD to store my other files. Then I decided to dual boot Windows 10 to use Office package.

I got another 500GB NVMe and installed Windows on that. After installation I saw thet 500GB SATA SSD its not listed in "My PC" because its ext4 file format.

I found it in Disk Management but it showed as "Unallocated". I logged out from Windows and logged in to Ubuntu, and saw that the ext4 drive was formatted and had a new 16MB partition type shown as "Microsoft Reserved". I deleted it and created again full ext4 partition. I tried using disktest but no help.

Is there any other way to recover data from that ext4 drive?

Comment: Your actions most certainly have made data recovery nearly impossible.  Just viewing the partition wouldn't have allocated the drive, unless you confirmed, the prompt that indicated the drive needed to be allocated.

Comment: @Ramhound on view disk manger it poped up window something gpt or mbr something i only add click that thing. not created a single drive

Comment: @JoepvanSteen thank you

Comment: You formatted and then allocated the drive by confirming that dialog. That was the reason you lost your files. Exact messages would’ve been helpful

Answer (score 1):

You did too much formats and partitioning so I am afraid the probability you can restore something is quite miniscule. You can try the utils for file recovery but be prepared they find nothing or restore broken file.